# Google Forms Response Confirmation Email Radio Buttons Not Rendering Properly in Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office

If I fill out a Google Form with multiple choice radio buttons, I get this response email in Gmail on the web:

[image: A screenshot of an email containing my responses to a Google Form]

When I open this same email in the Outlook 365 desktop client, it looks like this (after I click "Click here to download pictures"):

[image: The same email from the previous screenshot, but with the selected radio buttons missing]

Clicking "Click here to view it in a web browser" is entirely unhelpful and brings me to an unformatted mess of code in a web browser. Is there anything I can do to fix this as an end user so that the radio buttons show up as expected?

Comment: Nothing. Outlook uses Word as an editor for message bodies.

Comment: Do you mean, as the viewer? I'm not creating or editing any messages with Outlook.

Comment: Yes, Outlook uses Word for rendering and editing message bodies. The message creators should keep that in mind. I'd suggest contacting email creators then.

Comment: The email creators are Google.

Comment: The email recipient's client app is MS.